# Page layout Assignment to Individual User

Tags: community

Is there any way I can assign page layout on standard objects (Lead, Account and Opportunity) to a few individual users? Basically, I just created another page layout on lead and I want to assign 5 users to this layout.  I can create a another profile for these 5 users but is there any other way to go about this without creating more profiles?

Thanks,

-Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is not another way to assign page layout.  A user’s profile determines which page layout he or she sees.  The combination of the user profile and record type determine which page layout is displayed.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_layoutassign.htm